# Jqgrid table id - how to refer to it in jquery

Tags: jqgrid

I am having a bit of difficulty refering to a table element of the Jqgrid directly as it appears to be lacking a `id` element. Is there any way to do so?

When I look at the source code, I see a non-standard `aria-labelledby` element which I am assuming is Jqgrid's own but doesn't help me.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Are you configuring `id="grid_id"` for your table?

Comment: table has an id in my mark up, but jqgrid component takes it and changes it. I have solved the issue. see my reply.

Answer (score 0):

I have refered to the grid table as follows:

```
$('#gbox_mytableID table')
```

I am assuming one could also do

```
$('[aria-describedby=mytableID]')
```

But I haven't verified it.

My html looks like this:

```
<table id="mytableId"></table>
```